# What's the easiest way to read a FoxPro DBF file from Python?

Tags: python, foxpro, dbf, visual-foxpro

I've got a bunch of FoxPro (VFP9) DBF files on my Ubuntu system, is there a library to open these in Python?  I only need to read them, and would preferably have access to the memo fields too.

**Update**: Thanks @cnu, I used Yusdi Santoso's [`dbf.py`](http://www.physics.ox.ac.uk/users/santoso/dbf.py.src) and it works nicely.  One gotcha: The memo file name extension must be lower case, i.e. `.fpt`, not `.FPT` which was how the filename came over from Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this [recipe on Active State](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362715/).

There is also a [DBFReader module](http://code.google.com/p/lino/source/browse/lino/utils/dbfreader.py) which you can try.

For support for [memo fields](http://www.physics.ox.ac.uk/users/santoso/dbf.py.src).

Comment: The [DBFReader module](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/software/python/dbfreader.py) is now a dead link.

Comment: In memo fields program its give the number not exact data how to retrieve the data based on that index number where that stored .

Comment: Since Sep 2008 (time of the answer), there are many more options (Nov 2015), for example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbfread/, http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfpy/. I personally chose dbfread because it is well documented.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer [dbfpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfpy/). It supports both reading and writing of `.DBF` files and can cope with most variations of the format. It's the only implementation I have found that could both read and write the legacy DBF files of some older systems I have worked with.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to read a DBF file (with associated BAK, CDX, FBT, TBK files**) using the dbf package from PyPI http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf . I am new to python and know nothing about DBF files, but it worked easily to read a DBF file from my girlfriend's business (created with a music store POS application called AIMsi).

After installing the dbf package (I used aptitude and installed dbf version 0.88 I think), the following python code worked:

```
from dbf import *
test = Table("testfile.dbf")
for record in test:
    print record
    x = raw_input("")  # to pause between showing records
```

That's all I know for now, but hopefully it's a useful start for someone else who finds this question!

> April 21, 2012 SJK Edit: Per Ethan Furman's comment, I should point out that I actually don't know *which* of the data files were necessary, besides the DBF file.  The first time I ran the script, with only the DBF available, it complained of a missing support file.  So, I just copied over the BAK, CDX, FPT (not FBT as I said before edit), TBK files and then it worked.

Comment: This package doesn't yet support IDX/CDX files, although I hope to have that in place this year.

Comment: Are you sure it was FBT and not FPT? FPT files are the memo files. CDX is the index file although @Ethan says these aren't supported so that was unlikely to be the missing file. Along with the DBF these are the only 3 files you should need to read a DBF/Table.

Comment: This package is capable but documentation is not newbie friendly, dbfread provides more examples.

Comment: You might need to add test.open() before the for loop for this to work

Comment: @Steve are you sure it works with FPT files too? Or anyone else? I am trying to read FPT files but I am new to DBF and do not know what to do now. HELP please

Answer (score 9):

If you're still checking this,  I have a GPL FoxPro-to-PostgreSQL converter at https://github.com/kstrauser/pgdbf .  We use it to routinely copy our tables into PostgreSQL for fast reporting.

Comment: I coincidentally saw this while checking for something else. Now a postgreSQL lover,  coming from VFP and MS SQL, this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Check out http://groups.google.com/group/python-dbase

It currently supports dBase III and Visual Foxpro 6.0 db files... not sure if the file layout change in VFP 9 or not...

Answer (score 5):

It's 2016 now and I had to fiddle with the dbf package to get it to work. Here is a python3 version to just export a dbf file to a csv

```
import dbf

d=dbf.Table('mydbf.dbf')
d.open()
dbf.export(d, filename='mydf_exported.csv', format='csv', header=True)
```

I had some unicode error at first, but got around that by turning off memos.

```
import dbf

d=dbf.Table('mydbf.dbf', ignore_memos=True)
d.open()
dbf.export(d, filename='mydf_exported.csv', format='csv', header=True)
```