# DBF Large Char Field

Tags: oledb, dbf, clipper

I have a database file that I beleive was created with Clipper but can't say for sure (I have .ntx files for indexes which I understand is what Clipper uses).  I am trying to create a C# application that will read this database using the System.Data.OleDB namespace.

For the most part I can sucessfully read the contents of the tables there is one field that I cannot.  This field called CTRLNUMS that is defined as a CHAR(750).  I have read various articles found through Google searches that suggest field larger than 255 chars have to be read through a different process than the normal assignment to a string variable.  So far I have not been successful in an approach that I have found.

The following is a sample code snippet I am using to read the table and includes two options I used to read the CTRLNUMS field.  Both options resulted in 238 characters being returned even though there is 750 characters stored in the field.

Here is my connection string:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\datadir;Extended Properties=DBASE IV;

Can anyone tell me the secret to reading larger fields from a DBF file?

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT ITEM,CTRLNUMS FROM STUFF WHERE ITEM = '{0}'", stuffId);

        using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                stuff.StuffId = dr["ITEM"].ToString();

                // OPTION 1
                string ctrlNums = dr["CTRLNUMS"].ToString();

                // OPTION 2
                char[] buffer = new char[750];
                int index = 0;
                int readSize = 5;
                while (index < 750)
                {
                    long charsRead = dr.GetChars(dr.GetOrdinal("CTRLNUMS"), index, buffer, index, readSize);

                    index += (int)charsRead;

                    if (charsRead < readSize)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a description of the DBF structure here: http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html

What I think Clipper used to do was modify the Field structure so that, in Character fields, the Decimal Places held the high-order byte of the size, so Character field sizes were really 256*Decimals+Size.

I may have a C# class that reads dbfs (natively, not ADO/DAO), it could be modified to handle this case. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: Actually, that explains why this field is set with 2 decimal places.  I would be interested in seeing the class you mentioned.  Is it online somewhere?

Comment: I pulled out a hex editor and looked at the contents of the file.  The byte containing the field length is 0xEE or decimal 238.  So Marc, your formula does work out:  256*2+238 = 750  

Now to make the Jet OLEDB provider play along and use those calculations is another story.

Comment: I found this library that does a pretty good job of parsing a DBF file.  It doesn't do the calculation as noted above that was an easy code change to the FieldLength property.  http://code.google.com/p/dotnetdbf/

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my class isn't online, it was just a quick fix. If you still need it, I can e-mail it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you still looking for an answer? Is this a one-off job or something that needs doing regularly?

I have a Python module that is primarily intended to extract data from all kinds of DBF files ... it doesn't yet handle the `length_high_byte` = `decimal_places` hack, but it's a trivial change. I'd be quite happy to (a) share this with you and/or (b) get a copy of such a DBF file for testing.

Added later: Extended-length feature added, and tested against files I've created myself. Offer to share code with anyone who would like to test it still stands. Still interested in getting some "real" files myself for testing.

Answer (score 0):

3 suggestions that might be worth a shot...

1 - use Access to create a linked table to the DBF file, then use .Net to hit the table in the access database instead of going direct to the DBF.

2 - try the [FoxPro OLEDB provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1A87D8F-2D58-491F-A0FA-95A3289C5FD4&displaylang=en)

3 - parse the DBF file by hand.  Example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428237/how-do-i-extract-the-data-in-a-foxpro-memo-field-using-net).

My guess is that #1 should work the easiest, and #3 will give you the opportunity to fine tune your cussing skills. :)