# Writing to FoxPro-DBFs maintaining indexfiles (idx or cdx) with Python

Tags: python, indexing, dbf

I'm using the Python dbf lib by Ethan Furman - which is a great tool - to write to some Foxpro-tables ('free tables'). My problem is, that I need the accompanying index-files staying up to date. I have read, that Ethan Furman was working on it, but it was a notice from 2011. I couldn't find any info about, if he was successful. Is there a solution for it (or maybe with some other lib)?

Comment: I can read IDX files, but not update them.   My day job changed and dbf files are not a large part of the new one.

Comment: Thx for your comment, and all the rest :) I'm so in love with Python, that I didn't want to return to Foxpro at all. But there seems to be no way around in this case. After my data-processing in Python I will start a Foxpro-exe with a short append-routine from my Python-script. This should do the job as needed.

Comment: Check out these [Great Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535/whats-the-easiest-way-to-read-a-foxpro-dbf-file-from-python)

Comment: @joash I checked them, but couldn't find an answer to my question!?